# How do I add make a directory like a variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem, paths

Sorry for my weird question, I am very new to Linux and I am not sure what the correct terminology is.

I am writing a bash script, and I want to be able to add some directories to... I don't know what it's called. You know how you can represent your home directory by using `$HOME` ? Well, I want to be able to access a specific directory by using `$SPEC_DIR`. Is this possible?

Thank you, and sorry for the newbish phrasing... bear with me.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to set a variable. To make it available globally you can use:

```
export SPEC_DIR=/my/directory
```

To make this persist over reboot you can add it  to `$HOME/.bashrc` or more globally in `/etc/environment`.

If you want to use it just in one script you could just set it with:

```
SPEC_DIR=/my/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question entirely. I think you want to add directory and then cd to it? Am I right?

This will make directory with path in variable DIR. This does not add directory like a variable, but it creates variable, stores path in it and then creates directory with path from the variable.

```
DIR=/home/user/temp
mkdir $DIR
```

Then you can cd to it like this.

```
cd $DIR
```